# Python: Compare date and bulk update some fields

Tags: python, mysql, django

I created a refresh function for my Event Module, where if the Event date already passed, it will bulk update the status to 0.
*models.py*

```
class Events(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='id', primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    venue = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=eventpath, blank=True, null=True)
    manager = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    attendees = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=1)
```

This is how I add an event.

```
def uploadEvent(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        item = Events()
        item.title = request.POST.get('title')
        item.venue = request.POST.get('venue')
        date = request.POST.get('date')
        date_object = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%a %b %d %Y %I:%M %p')
        item.date = date_object
        item.manager = request.POST.get('manager')
        item.attendees = request.POST.get('attendees')
        item.description = request.POST.get('description')
        date_posted = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%a %b %d %Y %I:%M %p')
        item.date_posted = date_posted
        if len(request.FILES) != 0:
            item.image = request.FILES['image']

        item.save()
        return redirect('/amsai/events/')

    return render(request, 'admin/events_add.html')
```

And this is how I want to update all events. I converted the `obj.date` to `date()`

```
def refreshEvent(request):
   events = Events.objects.all()
   status = 0
   date = datetime.datetime.today().date()
   if events:
       for obj in events:
           if obj.date.date() < date:
               Events.objects.filter(*****).update(status=status)
   return redirect('/amsai/events/')
```

The problem is how can I filter those passed dates? I don't know what to write inside filter().

Comment: can you explain what flitter you want as date or something else?

Comment: @chetan dates that has already passed, just like in my if statement. If there are events that has already passed, its status should turn to "0" which is inactive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is asymptotically more efficient.

```
def refreshEvent(request):
    Events.objects.filter(date__lt=datetime.now()).update(status=False)
    return redirect('/amsai/events/')
```

The `filter()` now performs a database lookup directly and produces a `QuerySet` containing `Events` such that `Events.date` is `__lt` (less than) `datetime.now()`.

Don’t worry, `QuerySet`s are lazy so the `QuerySet` produced by `filter()` will not even be evaluated until `update()` is called.

Comment: This worked! I didn't know there was such `__lt`. I'll write this on my note. Thank you so much!